# How to exit from the execution of jquery code?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple (10) if statemnets stacked in a function, and need something like this:

```
$len=$("#user").val().length;
   if($len == 0) { do something and then - stop, exit, break ... whatever)
```

So, if `$len` is `0` - do something and - dont check anything more. Just exit from the execution.

Comment: What to stop? I see no each of foreach of while... In JavaScript U can  use break; or continue;. In jQuery.each() loop use 'return;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use return statement but it will take the execution control at end of function and skip all the statements between. or use if-else block or use switch.

```
if($len == 0) {

   do something and then - stop, exit, break ... whatever
   return;
)
```

*Use if-else*

```
if($len == 0) {

   do something and then - stop, exit, break ... whatever
   return;
)
else
if($len == 1) {

   do something and then - stop, exit, break ... whatever
   return;
)
//repeate if else
```

Using switch

```
switch($len)
{
 case 0:
  //execute code block 1
  break;
case 1:
  //execute code block 1
  break;
case 2:
  //execute code block 2
  break;
default:
  code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this...

```
$len=$("#user").val().length;
if($len == 0) { return false; }
```

I am returning `false` to make sure the event which invoked the function won't run anymore.

Comment: Thanks, ATOzTOA, I already accepted Adil's answer, but - that's it.